# Removing a row from ListView with a button click

Tags: android, listview, button, onclick, android-arrayadapter

I have a ListView whose rows comprise of some TextViews and a button. Upon a user pressing the button, I want to remove that parent that houses the button from the ListView. How do I access my custom ArrayAdapter's fields from within a nested method (onClickListener) though? All I have to work with is the View v. Am I suppose to call v.getParent() multiple times, or is there a better way to do it?

```
  @Override
  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
     ViewHolder holder = null;
     Action item = this.getItem(position);
     if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.action_holder_layout,
              parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.title = (TextView) convertView
              .findViewById(R.id.action_holder_title);
        holder.finishBtn = (Button) convertView
              .findViewById(R.id.finish_action_button);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
     } else
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
     holder.title.setText(item.getActionName());
     holder.finishBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
           //REMOVE THE ACTION FROM THE ADAPTER'S ARRAYLIST
        }
     });
     return convertView;
  }

  static class ViewHolder {

     private TextView title;
     private Button finishBtn;
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make `item` `final`:

```
final Action item = this.getItem(position);
```

and you can access it from `onClick`. Not a beautiful solution IMO, but will work:

```
remove(item);
```

Comment: It does indeed work, but what do you mean by it not being the most elegant solution? Is there something better? This seems to be the most simplistic way.

Comment: @TonyN.Tran I don't like creating `View.OnClickListener` every time `getView` is called. I do it [like this](https://github.com/mg6maciej/android-lists-adapters-demo/blob/master/ListsAndAdapters/src/pl/mg6/programistamag/linad/ButtonsProblemsExampleActivity.java#L105-L107). It's a bit more robust.

Comment: Okay, going with your preferred method, what do I implement in my custom onClickListener? If the button is pressed, View v (the button) is passed. Instead of declaring any variables as final, how would I figure out which ListView row the button was clicked from?

Comment: Oh wait! Perhaps I could store a tag in the button, and retrieve it later from my custom onClick! Does that sound viable?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran Using `setTag` to store item is basically the same as using `final`. These are ok solutions that have no real drawbacks. It's just me not liking to use `new` in certain places in code (`getView`, `onDraw`, `onTouchEvent`), because they may be called often and cause Garbage Collections. Using `convertView` and holder pattern is enough. You may ignore my remarks ;)

Comment: Well, I do desire the most efficient code possible. Having excessive garbage collections does sound bad, so...whatever it takes! Back to my question though: Without using final variables, or tag objects, how would I know which ListView row to remove?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran Actually in your case using tag will work if you have only a single `OnClickListener` assigned to every button. You then retrieve the item in `onClick` and may call `remove(item)`.

Comment: I see. Things would be different if I had OTHER listeners attached though, right?

Comment: @TonyN.Tran Not really. I just thought you would leave `new View.OnClickListener()` in `getView` in which case `final` and `setTag`+`getTag` are mostly the same. We are overdiscussing micro-optimization here. You will not see any difference if you simply use my original proposition.

Answer (score 1):

If you need access to your ListView (and consequently its Adapter), a better way than using `getParent().getParent()...` would be to use the setTag() method on your View. Since you are already using it to insert a ViewHolder as a Tag of your view, why not add another field

```
ListView parentListView;
```

to your ViewHolder and retrieve it later in the onClick?

You could also set the ListView directly as a tag on your button.

You could also just access the adapter or other methods and fields directly from your onClick code since you're using an anonymous class.

Comment: Do you think you can explain to me what exactly ARE tags? I can understand setting IDs integers as "tags", but I don't quite get the setTag and getTag methods for ListViews. I kind of just followed from a template and understand everything BUT the tags. Why am I passing an object in setTag()? And what am I retrieving with getTag()?

Comment: Setting a tag on a view is just a convenient way to store arbitrary data in a view. You can store any Object using setTag and retrieve the same Object later. The tags don't DO anything, they are for you to use as you need them

Comment: Oh. So they're not not for searching by tag or anything? That seemed to be the most intuitive thing to do with "tags". Thanks for the explanation though! Now I just need to figure out what exactly I can do with such a thing.

Comment: well, searching is one of things you can do (I actually forgot about that) but they're not there just for searching. you can use them for whatever purpose you need